# PrimeNG p-datatable sort indicator overlapped

Tags: primeng, primeng-datatable

I creating a table with sortable column. This is my code:

```
<p-dataTable [value]="list">
    <p-column field="name" header="name" sortable="true">
    </p-column>

    <p-column field="value" header="value" sortable="true">
    </p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

The problem is that the sortable indicators are overlapped in the first column, so on click it works on second column only.
With many other column it works in the same way. It seems like all the indicators are overlapped in the same place (see picture).
Any suggestions? 
Thanks[image]

Comment: Did you import PrimeNG CSS ? Can you provide a Plunker ?

Comment: Yes, I imported it. I think there is something in my style.css that overwrite primeNG rules but I can't understand which is.

Comment: Can you reproduce this problem in a Plunker ?